# how can i use old iphone 5 wifi only after ios 9 update.

Tags: ipod, unlock

It keeps asking to activate. I had att but got new att 6+. Now I just want to use it to play games and music. It wont get past activation. I have called att they cant unlock because sim is already deactivated. how do I get past this?

Answer (score 2):

Put in the sim from your 6+ to get past that screen.  Then take it out.  Only needs it to get past that one screen.